# apache 2.2 couldn't load a module on AIX 6.1

Tags: aix

I am testing an auth module with apache 2.2 server on 6.1 power AIX, 64 bit platform. The apache server doesn't start at all when I give my module path name in httpd.conf, it works fine on AIX 5.3 though with same module.

No crash, no other error message than following in error in error_log file:

httpd: Syntax error on line 423 of /home/apache22-aix64/installApache/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 9 of /
/home/apache22-aix64/installApache/conf/agent.conf: Cannot load /home/agent/apache/lib/auth-module.so into server: Not enough space

I have checked by increasing ThreadStackSize to 6mb, increased memory and other parameters, but issue is still the same. Issue is common in prefork n worker mode of apache server.

Comment: I've found something similar (the problematic module was libphp5.so), details here: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/aix-43/aix6-64-bit-apache-libphp5-dlopen-problem-4175545184/

Answer (score 0):

That's a new one on me... I'm guessing you are out of *something* (yea, brilliant guess right? ).  Try checking ulimit -a between the two systems (5.3 and 6.1).  I presume you are starting apache using the same type of id (non-root id with the same limits, permissions, etc).

I would also suggest tagging this with Apache to see if some apache guys might be able to help out.  We need to determine what is it out of -- memory, stack, disk space, paging space, etc.

Did you build this apache version yourself?

Comment: I am compling apache on aix 6.1 only
I have checked the memory between aix 6.1 n aix 5.3 and nothing exceptional is seen

bash-3.00$ ulimit -a
core file size        (blocks, -c) 1048575
data seg size         (kbytes, -d) 512000
file size             (blocks, -f) unlimited
max memory size       (kbytes, -m) 256000
open files                    (-n) 10000
pipe size          (512 bytes, -p) 64
stack size            (kbytes, -s) unlimited
cpu time             (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes            (-u) 4096
virtual memory        (kbytes, -v) unlimited